# PostgreSQL calculate sum and use result to return winner

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing sports analytics (beach volleyball) and got a table with `moves`. A move is, for example, a service ace, block error or attack winner (identified by tag). A move can increase the score for team a, team b or leave the score as is.

Some sample `moves` data.

```
set, tag, points_team_a, points_team_b
---,----,--------------,--------------
  1, 520,             1,             0
  1, 510,             0,             0
  1, 300,             0,             1
  1, 410,             0,             0
  1, 620,             0,             0
```

I've got a query to return the overall result.

```
select
  moves.set,
  sum(moves.points_team_a) as team_a,
  sum(moves.points_team_b) as team_b
from moves
where match_uuid = '26d41fc6-13d3-4af7-a5a3-3ec21bf06f03'
group by set
```

It shows that `team_a` won the first set 21:12 and the second set 21:18.

```
set, team_a, team_b
  1,     21,     12
  2,     21,     18
```

Is it possible to add the overall match result (in this case 2:0 for team_a) to the query?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select m.*,
       sum( (team_a > team_b)::int) over (order by set) as running_a_wins,
       sum( (team_b > team_a)::int) over (order by set) as running_b_wins
from (select m.set, sum(m.points_team_a) as team_a, sum(m.points_team_b) as team_b
      from moves m
      where m.match_uuid = '26d41fc6-13d3-4af7-a5a3-3ec21bf06f03'
      group by set
     ) m
```